# Table view populated from NSMutableArray not showing anything

Tags: ios

I am trying to populate a tableView with objects received from a JSON request.

This is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog (@"HE ENTRADO EN HISTORIAL VC");
    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.. HIDDEN HERE.. /?client=%@&date=%@", @"1",@"2015-3-16"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:apiURL];

    NSLog (@"HE MANDADO LA REQUEST DEL HISTORIAL");
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if(data.length) {
                                   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   if(responseString && responseString.length) {
                                       NSLog(@"dATOS RECIBIDOS EN HISTORIAL=%@", responseString);

                                       NSLog (@"HE RECIBIDO LA REQUEST DEL HISTORIAL");
                                       NSError *jsonError;
                                       NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                       NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                              error:&jsonError];
                                       NSArray *messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];

                                       historialServicios = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                                       // Parse and loop through the JSON
                                       for (dictionary in messageArray) {
                                           //datos de nivel objects
                                           NSString * code = [dictionary objectForKey:@"code"];
                                           NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];


                                           //datos de nivel client
                                           NSDictionary *level2Dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"client"];
                                           id someObject = [level2Dict objectForKey:@"email"];
                                           NSLog(@"ANTES DE ANADIR OBJETOS");

                                           [historialServicios addObject:@{@"code": code, @"date": date, @"email":someObject}];
                                           NSLog(@"DESPUES DE ANADIR OBJETOS");

                                           NSLog(@"NOMBRE===%@",someObject);

                                           NSString * email = someObject;
                                           NSLog(@"EMAIL=%@",email);
                                           NSLog(@"CODE=%@",code);
                                           NSLog(@"DATE=%@",date);

                                           //insertamos objetos en diccionario historialServicios
                                       }

                                        NSLog(@"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++SERVICIOS RECIBIDOS=%@", historialServicios);
                                   }

                               }
                           }];

    NSLog(@"NUMERO DE ITEMS=%lu", (unsigned long)[historialServicios count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The last NSLog doesn't appear in the log console. The content of the NSMutableArray are shown in the console:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++SERVICIOS RECIBIDOS=(
        {
        code = SV1000000103;
        date = "2015-03-18";
        email = "jose@gmail.com";
    },
        {
        code = SV1000000113;
        date = "2015-03-18";
        email = "jose@gmail.com";
    },
        {
        code = SV1000000104;
        date = "2015-03-16";
        email = "jose@gmail.com";
    },
...
```

But nothing is shown on the table.

Here the tableView methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return historialServicios.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *email = [[historialServicios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"email"];
    NSLog(@"VALOR DEL EMAIL=%@", email);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = email;
    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did your cell style is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` ? if NO try `cell.textLabel.text = email;`

Comment: You should call `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside the completion block after you build your array.  Your call will not have returned yet at the point you're calling it.

Comment: @HuyNghia, you are right. It works now.

Comment: @dan  , you are also right. It works now.

Comment: @dan, won't you put your comment as answer to my question? I would be glad accepting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `[self.tableView reloadData]` from inside the completion block just after "SERVICIOS RECIBIDOS=%@" line.

Calling it outside the block as you did, will make the table reloads it contents before you receive it from the server.

Hope it helps you, amigo.